# ¿cómo cambiar el tamaño de iconos y texto en visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vscode

¿Cómo se puede cambiar el tamaño de los iconos y nombre de los archivos en visual studio code?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el nombre de los archivos lo podes cambiar haciendo clic derecho y rename o apretas F2 sobre el archivo

Comment: @RamiroBarone gracias pero no busco cambiar el nombre, busco cambiar el tamaño de los iconos y el tamaño de la fente.